# Kendo UI Grid Reorderable Rows not reordering properly from bottom up

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have added the reorderable rows to true and when reordering by dragging and dropping a row, it doesn't work properly.
If I was to move Room 4 and drop it above the 1st row, it doesn't go there, sometimes other rows will go where I drop them but not always.

Here is a link to the demo [Reorder Row Drag and Drop](https://dojo.telerik.com/UBEnOZOl)

any idea's on why its not working properly?

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  LoadRoomsGrid();
});

function LoadRoomsGrid() {
  $("#RoomsGrid").empty();
  $("#RoomsGrid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
      data: roomData
    },
    dataBound: (e) => {

    },
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "RoomID",
        fields: {
          RoomID: {
            editable: false,
            hidden: true
          },
          roomName: {
            editable: true,
            type: "string",
            hidden: false
          }
        }
      }
    },
    columns: [{
        field: "RoomID",
        title: "RoomID",
        hidden: true
      },
      {
        field: "RoomName",
        title: "Rooms"
      }
    ],
    noRecords: {
      template: "No Rooms"
    },
    reorderable: {
      rows: true
    },
    change: function(e) {}
  });
}
const roomData = [{
    RoomID: 1,
    RoomName: "Room 1"
  },
  {
    RoomID: 2,
    RoomName: "Room 2"
  },
  {
    RoomID: 3,
    RoomName: "Room 3"
  },
  {
    RoomID: 4,
    RoomName: "Room 4"
  }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.1109/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.1109/styles/kendo.default-ocean-blue.min.css">

<div id="RoomsGrid"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that each item in the datasource must have a unique 'id' property for row reordering to work, even though that is not explicitly stated in the documentation.